# Jquery and materialize.js do not work in new app

Tags: jquery, angular, materialize, angular-cli

I wanted to add materialize-css to my new Angular2 app. 
After installing materialize-css and jquery via npm

```
npm install materialize-css
npm install jquery
```

I added them to my angular-cli.json file

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss",
    "styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/src/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/materialize-css/js/materialize.js"
]
```

The css works without any problem, but the js funtionality is missing. After that I tried to add materialize.js and jquery.js via cdn and added these lines to my index.html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Now everything works as expected. How can I get this working via the angular-cli.json file? Do I have to change something in there?

Comment: yes the path to the correct location